# How to make the following Vue code reactive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In this code:

```
handleChangeTab (toName, toIndex) {
  this.tabList.forEach((tab, index) => {
    tab.active = false
    this.$children[index].prefs.active = false
    if (tab.name === toName) {
      this.$children[toIndex].prefs.active = true
      tab.active = true
      console.log('tabList', this.tabList)
      console.log('this.$children', this.$children)
    }
  })
},
```

`this.tabList[1].active` becomes `true` when `handleChangeTab` is triggered. However, `this.$children[1]` becomes `false`. I think            `this.$children[toIndex].prefs.active` `=` `true` is messing up with Vue's reactive features.

How to fix this? In other words, how to write the reactive version of `this.$children[toIndex].prefs.active = true`?

Comment: Can you show your Vue's component code?

Comment: hard to say without seeing the whole picture, but `this.$set(this.$children[toIndex].prefs, 'active', true)` would be my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to deep copy data:

```
handleChangeTab (toName, toIndex) {
  const tabCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.tabList))
  tabCopy.forEach((tab, index) => {
    tab.active = false
    this.$children[index].prefs = {
      ...this.$children[index].prefs,
      active: false
    }

    if (tab.name === toName) {
      this.$children[index].prefs = {
        ...this.$children[index].prefs,
        active: true
      }
      tab.active = true
    }
  })
  this.tabList = tabCopy
}
```

But the better solution is passing props to your children component. Should not change children data directly from parent.

Comment: Thanks. Buts I get this error: [Vue warn]: Computed property "prefs" was assigned to but it has no setter.

Comment: Please include code to show how do you define `prefs`?